# Как загрузить изображение не используя input[type=file]?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Дана следующая разметка:

```
<div class="edit-item-image">
   <div class="edit-item-image__image-wrap">
   <!-- Тут должен появится предпросмотр изображения (тег <img>) перед отправкой данных формы на сервер -->
   </div>
   <div class="edit-item-image__btn-wrap">
      <button class="button button--small button--black-border edit-item-image__btn">Добавить</button>
      <button class="button button--small button--black-border edit-item-image__btn">Удалить</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Данная разметка является частью формы `<form><form/>`.
И по этой разметке мне нужно создать JSX/TSX реакт-компонент.
Собственно создать компонент не проблема.
Проблема как реализовать загрузку файла с ПК.
Единственное что удалось по теме загуглить, это использовать скрытый `input[type="file"]` и при клике на кнопку вызывать срабатывание этого скрытого инпута.

Но возможно в Реакте есть какие-то способы реализовать загрузку файла иным способом? Какой-нибудь экзотический хук про который я не знаю, или на крайний случай, какой-нибудь npm-пакет, решающий поставленную задачу?

UPD. Уже больше часа на самом деле гуглю и ничего внятного не нашёл.
Однозначно не берусь утверждать в силу отсутствия опыта, но есть ощущение, что мне просто косячную вёрстку подсунули и нужно выкинуть `<button>` и заменить его стилизованным `<input type="file">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам нужно сделать React компонент, тогда скройте `input[type="file"]` и воспользуйтесь хуком useRef,чтобы получить ссылку на `input[type="file"]` Потом создайте кнопку и подпишите ее на событие `onClick` и в функции которая будет срабатывать при нажатии на кнопку программно используя ссылку на `input[type="file"]` кликните по `input[type="file"]`.
как-то так:

```
const inputFile = useRef(null);

const hendlerInput = () => {
    inputFile.current.click();
  };

<button onClick={ hendlerInput }>Добавить</button>

<input type="file" ref="inputFile" className="hidden" />
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо за предложенный вариант.
Наверное так и придётся сделать. Подожду ещё немного, если другой альтернативы никто не предложит (а скорее всего другой альтернативы и нет), то приму ваш ответ как правильный :)